# Cant figure out simple haskell recursion problem

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a simple haskell program that sums up the digits of an integer for example my integer is 888 so the sum should be 8+8+8=24. I got this part down but I want my program to keep going until there is nothing to add for example after the addition of 8+8+8 = 24 it should add 2 + 4 = 6 and then return 6. Thanks for help !

```
import System.IO
import Data.List

integer = 888

todigits :: Integral x => x -> [x]
todigits 0 = []
todigits x = todigits (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]

add::[Int]->Int
add (x:xs) = sum(x:xs)

added = add (todigits integer)

main = do
    print(added)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine for just one iteration. You just need to call it recursively until you get a 1-digit result (or an empty list, of course).

We'll start with your existing function, which I've renamed and rewritten so that it returns the list in the opposite order (with the units digit first). This isn't necessary at all, and you can use exactly your previous definition (since the only thing we're interested in so far is the sum of the list, for which the order doesn't matter), but this will be more convenient if you need to reconstruct the number from the digit list (and should also I think perform a bit better):

```
todigitsOnce :: Integral x => x -> [x]
todigitsOnce 0 = []
todigitsOnce x = x `mod` 10 : todigitsOnce (x `div` 10)
```

And here is the recursive `toDigit` function:

```
toDigit :: Integral x => x -> [x]
toDigit x
    | length firstResult < 2 = firstResult
    | otherwise = toDigit . sum $ firstResult
    where firstResult = todigitsOnce x
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I understand it a little bit better now. But there is another problem the code compiles but when I run it the program hangs without any output

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not able to debug it at the moment, sounds like there's an infinite recursion going on. Will let you know when I come up with a fix. (Happy to take suggestions from the gallery as well :) )

Comment: OK, working through it by hand I've figured out why it's in an infinite loop. I forgot I need a non-recusive case in `firstResult` too! Will edit straight away to add this. (Actually, in doing so I've realised there were bigger problems. Apologies again, let me completely rewrite this...)

Comment: Right, apologies for this, turned out my main mistake was simply that I forgot to sum the list before making the recursive call. I am suitably embarrassed, please try the new version and let me know if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A positive number and its digit sum are always congruent modulo 9. What's more, since all nonzero numbers have at least one positive digit and no negative digits, there is no way to get a digit sum of 0 from a positive number. Therefore:

```
digitSum x = case (x, x `mod` 9) of
    (0, _) -> 0
    (_, 0) -> 9
    (_, v) -> v
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> digitSum 888
6
```

This function may not do what you expect on negative numbers -- but then, the original also doesn't handle negative numbers gracefully, so... =)

Answer (score 1):

At alternative answer, in particular because you're doing recursive digit (base 10) sum and default `show` instance is base 10, you can round-trip via strings and nicely write with a view pattern,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

digitSum :: Int -> Int
digitSum x@(show -> (_:"")) = x
digitSum (show -> cs) = digitSum $ sum . map ( read . (:[]) ) $ cs
```

If the string representation is any single character (ie. `0 <= x <= 9`) then just return `x`, otherwise recurse on the sum of the integers in the string representation.

You can still use view patterns (imo) nicely without roundtripping, but it does require the auxiliary function to express an integer as a list of its digits,

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

digitList :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
digitList 0 = [0]
digitList n = unfoldr f n
    where f 0 = Nothing
          f i = Just . swap $ i `divMod` 10

digitSum' :: (Integral a) => a -> a
digitSum' (digitList -> x:[]) = x
digitSum' (digitList -> xs) = digitSum' $ sum xs
```